# Animation: Applying changes to colors in every frame of the sequence

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, animation, image-editing, painting

I have this animation of a Skeleton's Walkcycle and I would like to paint his insides purple, but I want this action to be reproduced in the various layers ofthe animation, so I don't have to paint each one individually - which would take me very long. The skeleton shape is very irregular so the purple colour would have to adapt to the shape of the character on specific frames. I tried blending options and other adjustments. What are your thoughts on this?

[image: Skeleton Animation]

Comment: As you've discovered, the work involved for each frame of an animation can be substantial. Have you considered to advance to a program specifically aimed to animation? Adobe Animate is one that comes to mind, but there are others on the 'net.

Answer (score 1):

Cool drawing! I would love to see the running animation.

Anyway, I don't think there is a way to automate this kind of cut-out 100% in Photoshop. In order for such a tool to work, you would have to have a massive interface to tell Photoshop exactly what you need it to do, and it might take longer to program the tool than to just do it manually.

This might be easier in applications dedicated to animation, but when you are working with hand drawn illustrations (as opposed to vector drawing) there will always be tons of manual labor involved.

That being said, depending on how your document is set up and what kind of result you are expecting, there might be an easy way to do this.

I can see that you have already deleted the background on each frame, so they all have transparent backgrounds. This enables a quick way of adding color to every non-transparent pixel of a layer:

- Add a colored layer above the layer (I'm using a *Solid Color* layer to keep it dynamic).
- Set the colored layer's *Blend Mode* to *Multiply*.
- Hold down *Alt*, and click between the layer with the drawing and the new colored layer.

[image]

This also works for groups, so if you place all of your drawing in on group, you can perform the same trick on all layers at once:

[image]

This might ruin your animation though, so you probably need to experiment a little to find a way that suits your workflow.

If you need a more detailed coloring where the bones are white etc. I'm afraid you need to go through every layer manually.